# Make UIImageView Clickable and Send To Website

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I am making UIImageView instances. I am having trouble making the UIImage clickable. I also would like the UIImage when clicked to send the user to a link on the Internet. How can I accomplish this? I have tried adding tap gestures and such but am having no luck. You can see this with the code that is commented out.

/*File 1 Model File*/

```
import Foundation

class Book : NSObject{
    var thumbnailImageName: String?
    var title : String?
    var subTitle : String?
}
```

/*File 2 Cell File*/

```
import UIKit

class BookCell: BaseCell{
    var book: Book?{
        didSet{
            thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named:  (book?.thumbnailImageName)!)

            titleLabel.text = book?.title

            subtitleTextView.text = book?.subTitle
        }
    }

    var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()

        // let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: imageView, action: #selector(BookCell.tapBlurButton(_:)))

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "")
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.tag = 0
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        // imageView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        // imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        return imageView
    }()

    let userProfileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Gary Vee Profile Pic 1")
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 22
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    let separatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1)

        return view
    }()

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "DailyVee 199"
        label.userInteractionEnabled = false
        return label
    }()

    let subtitleTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.text = "When a street hustler make 130 million"
        textView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-4,0,0)
        textView.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        return textView
    }()

    let purchaseButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .System) // let preferred over var here
        button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        button.addTarget(button, action: #selector(Books.tapBlurButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    override func setupViews(){
        addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        addSubview(separatorView)
        addSubview(userProfileImageView)
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(subtitleTextView)
        addSubview(purchaseButton)

        addContraintsWithFormat("H:|-16-[v0]-16-|", views: thumbnailImageView)

        addContraintsWithFormat("H:|-16-[v0(44)]", views: userProfileImageView)

        //Vertical constraints
        addContraintsWithFormat("V:|-16-[v0]-8-[v1(44)]-16-[v2(1)]|", views: thumbnailImageView, userProfileImageView, separatorView)

        addContraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: separatorView)

        //top constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute:.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        //left constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: userProfileImageView, attribute:.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        //right constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute:.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        //height constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute:.Height, multiplier: 0, constant: 20))

        //top constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: titleLabel, attribute:.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 4))
        //left constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: userProfileImageView, attribute:.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        //right constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute:.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        //height constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute:.Height, multiplier: 0, constant: 30))
    } 
}
```

/*File 3 Class File*/

```
class Books : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var books: [Book] = {
        var askGaryVee = Book()
        askGaryVee.thumbnailImageName = "askgaryvee_book"
        askGaryVee.title = "#ASKGARYVEE: ONE ENTREPRENEUR'S TAKE ON LEADERSHIP, SOCIAL MEDIA, AND SELF-AWARENESS"
        askGaryVee.subTitle = "by Gary Vaynerchuk"

        var jabJabJabRightHook = Book()
        jabJabJabRightHook.thumbnailImageName = "jab_jab_jab_right_hook_book"
        jabJabJabRightHook.title = "JAB, JAB, JAB, RIGHT HOOK: HOW TO TELL YOUR STORY IN A NOISY SOCIAL WORLD"
        jabJabJabRightHook.subTitle = "by Gary Vaynerchuk"

        var theThankYouEconomy = Book()
        theThankYouEconomy.thumbnailImageName = "the_thank_you_economy_book"
        theThankYouEconomy.title = "The Thank You Economy"
        theThankYouEconomy.subTitle = "by Gary Vaynerchuk"

        var crushIt = Book()
        crushIt.thumbnailImageName = "cursh_it_book"
        crushIt.title = "CRUSH IT! WHY NOW IS THE TIME TO CASH IN ON YOUR PASSION"
        crushIt.subTitle = "by Gary Vaynerchuk"

        return[askGaryVee, jabJabJabRightHook, theThankYouEconomy, crushIt]
    }()

    func tapBlurButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Please Help!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        navigationItem.title = "Books"

        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        collectionView?.registerClass(BookCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"cellId")
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return books.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookCell

        cell.book = books[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height = (view.frame.width - 16 - 16) * 9 / 16
        return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, height + 16 + 68)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

}
```

Comment: The target for your tap gesture should be `self`. Furthermore a `UIImageView` is not a `UIControl` so you cannot add control events to it.

Comment: Is there something else I can do? I have a button also in this section. Can I make the button send the user to a website?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to add a clear `UIButton` on top of your `UIImageView` and set the frame of your `UIButton` to be the same as your `UIImageView`. Then you can use the `UIButton`'s `IBAction` to send the user to the link.

```
var tumbnailButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: thumbnailImageView.frame)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapBlurButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()
```

**EDIT:**
The above code might throw an error since it is a computed property. Try replacing

```
var tumbnailButton: UIButton = {
```

with

```
var tumbnailButton: UIButton {
```

and remove the parenthesis at the end.

If that doesn't work, try

```
var tumbnailButton: UIButton {
    get{
        let button = UIButton(frame: thumbnailImageView.frame)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapBlurButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        return button
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you

Comment: You could also add a TapGestureRecognizer straight onto the image and it works well too!

Comment: When I use this code above, I am getting an error back regarding the thumbnailImageView. It says "Instance member thumbnailImageView cannot be used on type Bookcell"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was away for Easter. Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make this class which inherits UITapGestureRecognizer

```
open class BlockTap: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    fileprivate var tapAction: ((UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)?

public override init(target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
    super.init(target: target, action: action)
}

public convenience init (
    tapCount: Int = 1,
    fingerCount: Int = 1,
    action: ((UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)?) {
        self.init()
        self.numberOfTapsRequired = tapCount

        #if os(iOS)
        self.numberOfTouchesRequired = fingerCount
        #endif

        self.tapAction = action
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BlockTap.didTap(_:)))
}

open func didTap (_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    tapAction? (tap)
}
}
```

then make an extension of UIImageView or UIView

```
extension UIImageView {
        public func addTapGesture(tapNumber: Int = 1, action: ((UITapGestureRecognizer) -> ())?) {
            let tap = BlockTap(tapCount: tapNumber, fingerCount: 1, action: action)
            addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Then You can use this as

```
imageView?.addTapGesture(action: {[unowned self] (_) in
                //Do whatever on click of image
})
```

In Your code you can use this as

you can use addTapGesture to any imageview in your code like this

```
    let userProfileImageView: UIImageView = {
     let imageView = UIImageView() 
       imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Gary Vee Profile Pic 1") 
       imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 22 
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true 
       imageView?.addTapGesture(action: {[unowned self] (_) in
            //Code you want to execute on click of Imageview
            imageView?.cornerRadius = 4.0
            imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        }) 
          return imageView 
       }()
```

on click of imageView cornerRadius of image will change to 4.0.

Comment: where would I use the imageview?addtapgesture? where at in the code?

Comment: Edited the answer. You can use addTapGesture on imageview in viewDidLoad. whenever the image will be tapped the block of addTapGesture will be called.
Hope That Helps

Comment: getting error whenever I put "imageView?.addTapGesture(action: {[unowned self] (_) in". If you look at my code above you will notice that I have 3 different files. A module, cell class that overrides a base cell and another file where I manually create the cells for the UICollectionViewController. Also putting that code inside of the viewDidLoad() will not work because imageView is not declared in that file. Its declared in the cell file. not the file with the UICollectionViewController

Comment: In that case if you want to add a tapGesture on image inside a cell. you can call addTapGesture on **cell.imageView** in **cellForItemAtIndexPath**. Hope it helps.